# How to avoid pyramid of cases?

Tags: haskell, either

I have code structured like the example below. I'm pretty sure there should be a way to structure it much more sanely. I would assume Either (or Error) monad could help, but I don't know where to start with that. Any pointers to get me going in the right direction?

```
data Data1 = Data1 { d2Id :: String }
data Data2 = Data2 { d3Id :: String }
data Data3 = Data3 { d4Id :: String }

getData1 :: String -> IO (Either String Data1)
getData2 :: String -> IO (Either String Data2)
getData3 :: String -> IO (Either String Data3)

process :: Data1 -> Data2 -> Data3 -> IO ()

get :: String -> IO ()
get id = do
  r1 <- getData1 id
  case r1 of
    Left err -> print err
    Right d1 -> do
      r2 <- getData2 $ d2Id d1
      case r2 of
        Left err -> print err
        Right d2 -> do
          r3 <- getData3 $ d3Id d2
          case r3 of
            Left err -> print err
            Right d3 -> do
              process d1 d2 d3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm reopening this question because I think it would be helpful to see 
how to transform this kind of specific code.

We'll need a few imports:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Either
```

Then transform your `get` function by applying `EitherT` to each IO-action which signals an error by returning an `Either`:

```
-- get' :: EitherT String IO ()
get' id = do
  d1 <- EitherT $ getData1 id
  d2 <- EitherT $ getData2 (d2Id d1)
  d3 <- EitherT $ getData3 (d3Id d2)
  liftIO $ process d1 d2 d3
```

Note that we don't use `EitherT` for `process`. Instead we use `liftIO` since `process` doesn't signal an error.

GHC should be able to infer the type signature so you don't need to provide it.

To run the new version, use `runEitherT` which will return an `Either` value in the IO-monad:

```
doit :: String -> IO ()
doit id = do
  res <- runEitherT (get' id)
  case res of
    Left err -> print err
    Right d  -> return ()
```

Comment: Why was the question closed?

Comment: It was marked as a dup. This kind of question has come up before, but not exactly in this context, so I decided to re-open it and add an answer.

Comment: It seems EitherT is not on Stackage, does that mean that the preferred approach is to use Except for such control flow? https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=EitherT

Answer (score 1):

Since support for runEitherT has been dropped in [Either-5](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/either-5/changelog), I would recommend using `whenLeft` and `whenRight` from `Data.Either.Combinators`. Your code could be rewritten as follows:

```
get :: String -> IO ()
get id = do
           r1 <- getData1 id
           whenLeft r1 print
           whenRight r1 (\d1 -> do 
                                  r2 <- getData2 $ d2Id d1
                                  whenLeft r2 print
                                  whenRight r2 (d2 -> 
                                                   [rest of code...] )
                         )
```

Of course, this would lead to messy code, so whenever I do this, I make sure to end the computation whenever a `Left` is encountered. The `Except` monad is great for this. Using it, the code would be rewritten as follows:

```
get :: String -> ExceptT String IO ()
get id = do
           r1 <- liftIO $ getData1 id
           whenLeft r1 throwError 
           r2 <- liftIO $ getData2 $ d2Id (fromRight r1)
           whenLeft r2 throwError
           r3 <- liftIO $ getData3 $ d3Id (fromRight r2)
           whenLeft r3 throwError
           liftIO $ process (fromRight r1) (fromRight r2) (fromRight r3)
```

This will make the `fromRight` statements never fail, because whenever r1,r2 or r3 are `Left`, the computation will throw an error and it will stop there.